# $S _4$ the symmmetric group

Tags: group-theory

Let $S_{4}$ the symmmetric group of order $24$ and let an involution $%
\alpha \in S_{4}$ and $\alpha \not\in V$ ($\alpha $ fixed) where $V$ is normal Klein group in $%
S_{4}.$

I want to show that $\left[ S_{4},\alpha \right] =A_{4}$ where $\left[
S_{4},\alpha \right] =\left\langle x^{-1}x^{\alpha };x\in S_{4}\right\rangle
$

It is clear that $\left[ S_{4},\alpha \right] \leq A_{4}.$ Why $\left[
S_{4},\alpha \right] \geq A_{4}$?

Comment: There are multiple isomorphic copies of $V$ in $S_4$. Do you mean $\alpha$ is not in any of them?

Comment: $S_4$ is so small I think you should just start calculating elements in $[S_4, \alpha]$ till you realize you've got all of $A_4$.

Comment: @Alex: Only one is normal though

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Ah right, I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the involution $\alpha$ lies outside the normal Klein $4$-subgroup $V,$ it has the form $(ab)$ for $a \neq b.$ Note then that $(ab)(abc)(ab) = (cba).$ Hence
$[(abc),\alpha] = (abc).$ Thus $[S_{4},\alpha]$ contains an element of order $3$.
But $[S_{4},\alpha] \lhd S_{4}$ and all $3$-cycles are conjugate within $S_{4},$ so that $[S_{4},\alpha]$ contains all eight $3$-cycles of $S_{4},$ so contains $A_{4}.$

Comment: Lima: Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

*HINT:* You can ignore the statement about $V$. As an involution, $\alpha$ is either of the form $(a\,b)$ or $(a\,b)(c\,d)$, wlog. $(1\,2)$ or $(1\,2)(3\, 4)$. For both cases, find suitable elements of $S_4$ such that the corresponding commutartors give you a generating set for $A_4$.

Comment: The involutions of the form $(ab)(cd)$ are in $V$, and they give $[S_{4},\alpha] = V.$

Comment: Lima:I think that equality is not true

Comment: What I meant here was that the case $\alpha = (12)(34)$ does not occur, because all such involutions lie in the normal subgroup $V$, and that, in any case, if $\alpha = (ab)(cd)$ for $a,b,c,d$ all different, we would have$[S_{4},\alpha]  =V.$

Comment: Lima: It was very clear now. Thank you!